# Why there is no difference between passing in the memo dict and not passing it?

Tags: python, dynamic-programming, fibonacci, memoization

So I have this memoized algorithm for the Fibonacci sequence and I faced something a little strange, there is no impact on the time complexity if I pass the **memo** dict in **line 4**, or if I don't, I want to understand why? isn't **memo** supposed to be empty in the later recursive calls?

here's the code without passing **memo** in **line 4**:

```
def fib(n , memo = {}):
    if(n<=2): return 1
    if(n in memo): return memo[n]
    memo[n] = fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)
    return memo[n]
```

and here it is when I pass it:

```
def fib(n , memo = {}):
    if(n<=2): return 1
    if(n in memo): return memo[n]
    memo[n] = fib(n-1 , memo) + fib(n-2 , memo)
    return memo[n]
```

you can try it there is no difference in the time complexity.

Comment: Why would you expect a difference in the output?

Comment: because in javascript there is

Comment: That's surprising. I'd like to see that.

Comment: I'm sure about that, you can try it n see.

Comment: of course, when I said output I meant its time complexity

Comment: Try `print(fib.__defaults__)` before and after running `fib` ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`memo` will be initialized to the default value (empty dict) **exactly once**. After that, the default value memo is the previously initiated instance, so inside the function, you are always modifying the same instance of the dict.

Check this passage from the [python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#default-argument-values):

**Important warning**: The default value is evaluated only once. This makes a difference when the default is a mutable object such as a list, dictionary, or instances of most classes. For example, the following function accumulates the arguments passed to it on subsequent calls: [...]